# Multiple "Error CS0234" causing MSBuild to fail in VSTS

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, visual-studio-2017

I have an MVC5 web application, written in VS2017. It targets .NET 4.6.1. On my development machine it builds and runs without a problem. I can even use the Publish feature in VS to publish it to my server and it works perfectly.

I'm now trying to instantiate CI in VSTS, something I've done successfully plenty of times before with other projects. When the Build runs, the MSBuild task fails. The logs show many instances of basically the same CS0234 error, relating to missing references. For example:

[image]

I've done a lot of Googling on this and tried all sorts of things. I've removed and re-added NuGet packages. I've made sure that the `Copy Local` attriubute of all my references is `True`. I've tried manually specifying the C# Language Version in the project's advanced build settings (I'm clutching at straws!).

Initially I was trying to get this working with a locally-hosted agent (which builds other projects without problems), and so I've gone onto that machine, installed VS2017 and rebuilt and run the project in VS on it, again without a problem. In any case, I don't think the issue relates to the machine running the build agent because I get the same errors when I use an Azure-hosted build agent.

Most of the questions I've found on SO and elsewhere relate to a particular reference apparently being missing. As you can see, in my case it seems like just about ALL the referenced assemblies are missing!

I've shared the full Build task log [here](https://1drv.ms/t/s!AoxUcQPbia2lmtMh_azCpdM-9rgGsg). You'll see the bulk of the errors begin on line 1059, but there are warnings of the problems to come on line 129 (amongst others), which says:

```
##[warning]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): Warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.
```

So obviously the necessary files are missing, but why? Why would they be missing even on the Azure-hosted agent machine? And, most importantly, how do I restore/install them where they need to be? As I say, the Solution builds fine on my own machine.

Comment: Does your build definition include a nuget restore task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to these steps below to modify your build definition:

1. Add **NuGet Installer** task (Path to solution or packages.config: `**\*.sln`; Installation Type: `Restore`)

[image]

2. Change NuGet Version to **4.0** in Advanced section
3. Queue build with **Hosted VS2017** agent.

Comment: When I search available task types to add for "nuget", there are only four matches: NuGet Command, NuGet Packager, NuGet Publisher and NuGet Restore. I assumed that last one was the one you meant, but when I add it, it does not offer any of the options (Installation Type, NuGet Version) you described. 

I was already using the Hosted VS2017 agent.

Comment: @PhilipStratford Change the version to 0.*. I updated my answer.